# Wildcard parameter in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, wildcard

in my query I use a parameter for choosing the material number.
This parameter accesses a field from my infoset (SAP) which has the following format:

15F5K1E-350A (there are thousands of different combinations)

Later on I want to evaluate groups which are formed this way: xxF5xxE-xxxx

Is it possible to generate a parameter field which allows me to work with wildcards or sth.?
The original wildscard from SAP (X / *) are not working here.

Thanks in advance, I hope my problem gets clear.

Comment: Are you wanting to filter results based upon the format you provided as an input mask where it enforces the number of characters and the position/index of the specified values of F, 5, and E?  Or could you work with a more loose evaluation where F5 and E are treated as substrings that could appear anywhere within the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Crystal Reports one can use the `Like`-operator.

Create a parameter-field of type string where you can enter the filter-pattern later.

Supported placeholders are

- `*` (zero ore more characters)

and

- `?` (exactly one character).

To filter by the example you posted, the pattern would look like this: `??F5??E-????`

Then you can use following formula to do what you want if the pattern is matched or not:

```
If {Table.MaterialNumber} Like {?FilterParam} Then
    True // Pattern matched
Else
    False // Pattern not matched
```

Comment: Hey Mat! I do not understand where I should enter the filter-pattern. In the Parameter-assistent?

And where do I place this formula? In my understanding this formula needs to be applied on the parameter field directly after starting the query.

Comment: I want to use the parameter with the wildcards in the "Selection-Assistant" -> "Data set" to limit the results with entering (for example) "15F5K1E-350A". CR should look for matching data using "??F5??E-????" then.

Comment: It depends on how the report should work in the end. My Idea is to place the formula in the Selection-Assistant. The parameter-field should be placed somewhere on the report. If the report is opened, the dialog for entering a parameter-value will be shown. There you can enter any pattern you want.

Comment: Ah I think I got it, thanks a lot!
Maybe I will extend this thread later on if I got problems again.

Comment: I just recognized, that in my wildcard "++S6+++-++++" that only the "S" is observed for the search. Is there any possibility to let him search for the exact parameter?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean.... `+` is not a supported placeholder. Maybe it's the best if you ask a new question with the exact description of the problem, instead of a comment.

Comment: Okay, see you there :)

Comment: New question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63516977/problem-with-wildcard-parameter-in-crystal-reports