# Problem with wildcard parameter in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, wildcard

I´ve created a wildcard in crystal using the like-function:

`If {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-MATNR} Like {?Parameter field with wildcard} Then True Else False`

My entered pattern looks like this (for example): ??S6???-????

What I get back is kinda strange. Crystal is now looking for everything with an "S" in the third place, what comes after that "S" in the parameter field is ignored. So everything looking like ??S????-???? is found.

Is there a way to extend the Like-function (or any other option) to make him look for the exact input of the parameter field?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot recreate this scenario. It works just like it should. Maybe the problem lies somewhere "deeper" in the report.

Comment: Hey Mat, this is the code I entered in the dataset selection wizard:
-----
If {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-MATNR} Like {?Artikel mit Wildcard} Then
    True
Else
    False and
{Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-BWART} = "601" and
{Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-WERKS} = "0010" and
{Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-WADAT_IST} = {?Datum} and
{Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-VTWEG} = "01"
-----

Maybe I used the LIKE-function the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine that `...Then True Else False and...` is really intended and think what you need is this:

```
If {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-MATNR} Like {?Artikel mit Wildcard}
   and {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-BWART} = "601"
   and {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-WERKS} = "0010"
   and {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-WADAT_IST} = {?Datum}
   and {Z_QM_INFOSET_CR_NEU.ZQM_DELIVERY-VTWEG} = "01" Then
    True
Else
    False
```

Comment: I just changed the code, but there is no difference visible.
What exactly does happen if it is "TRUE"?

Comment: If this formula is entered in the selection-formula, then `True` means "select this row" and `False` means "don't select this row".

Comment: Here is an example I get with the exact code from your answer:

Wildcard is: ??S6???-????
Result is: A3SMHF2-84J0

The "6" after the "S" is ignored in the wildcard and I I receive the corresponding result.

Comment: As already mentioned in comments, I can not recreate this. I've created an empty report with following formula which returns `False`:    `"A3SMHF2-84J0" Like "??S6???-????"`

Comment: I think I found my problem. To solve it, I need to implement another Wildcard parameter field which is checked after the first one.
I tried a few ways to enter it, but no one worked. 

Can you please give me a hint how to code that?

The name of the parameter field is "wildcard_name" and the name of the field to be compared is "text_name".

Comment: I don't understand how a second parameter would solve this? Anyway, that's not how SO works. If this question is answered, mark an answer (green checkmark) or add your own answer if mine is not useful. Then ask a new question with the exact details of what you want to achieve, what you've tried and where you're stuck.